# Are Canadianisms like "aboat" equally common on the American side of the border, adjacent to it?

Tags: american-english, dialects, north-american-english, accent, canadian-english

Most Canadians live close the the border. If you cross to the American side of border, in a rural area, do Canadianisms (1) like "[aboat](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/aboat)" (2) suddenly become much less common?

---

Since this created controversy, allow me to quote the dictionaries:

(1)

**Canadianism**

*noun*

1. a word, expression, ***or other language feature*** that is characteristically Canadian.
2. the state of being Canadian, or the character and spirit characteristic of Canadians.

(2)

- https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/aboat "This spelling has been used to represent Canadian raising"
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aboot
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aboat

Comment: That's not a Canadianism. There is a vowel change known as ["Canadian Raising"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Canadian+Raising%22) which changes the allophone of /aw/ before voiceless consonants, and it's common in Canada and in parts of the northern US.

Comment: @JohnLawler *"That's not a Canadianism"* -- Why do you say that? "Canadianism" is defined as "a word, expression, or *other language feature* that is characteristically Canadian". If "characteristically Canadian" means `P(X | speaker is Canadian) > P(X)` (conditional and marginal probabilities, respectively), then it's a Canadianism.

Comment: First, it's not "aboot". No such word exists and that spelling doesn't represent Canadian speech. Second, the phenomenon you're referring to is not  "Canadianism", but a variant diphthong -- a **sound**, not a word -- parallel to the odd way all North Americans pronounce diphthongs before voiceless consonants. Canadians are just consistent, in using the same rule for /aw/ that everybody uses for /ay/. For Americans and Canadians, the vowels in _five_ and _fife_ are different - listen and you'll hear it. For Canadians but not USAers, the same is true of _loud_ and _lout_.

Comment: @JohnLawler I think this could be expanded into an interesting question.  I wonder how porous a national border is to accent. It seems to me there's an aspect of "which tribe do you come from and which do you want/not want to be identified with" when it comes to accent, not just "who do you live near". This article about [the evolution of the "pop-punk" accent](https://www.atlasobscura.com/articles/i-made-a-linguistics-professor-listen-to-a-blink-182-song-and-analyze-the-accent) is interesting. A performance accent is another pair of sleeves though because it's part of the art.

Comment: Excerpt from the article I linked above: "The California Shift has another name north of the border: the Canadian Shift. From Ontario on west to British Columbia, the Canadian accent has been rotating in much the same way as it has in California. There are differences; the classic Canadian “about,” which is more like “aboat,” is not mirrored in California. But the Canadian dialect found itself faced with the cot-caught merger, which had a similar effect on the rest of the vowels as what happened in California."

Comment: @ColleenV With all respect, I doubt it. My experience discussing phonetics online using only letters and IPA is that it's a losing proposition, because: (a) most of our users don't hear native English; (b) those that are not native speakers have been taught a dumpload of bad "rules"; (c) those that are native speakers have been taught a **different** dumpload of equally bad, but contradictory, "rules"; (d) everybody thinks letters and printed language came first and matter most; and, (e) practically nobody has studied phonetics or the sounds of English.

Comment: @JohnLawler I agree with you, it's tough to have a meaningful discussion about phonetics in this environment. I am really just trying to trick people into posting something more interesting than "I heard a person talk like that once". I think regional variations like this are interesting, but I don't know enough about the topic to find the papers to read that are written at a level deep enough to satisfy my curiosity but not so technical  I can't understand them.

Comment: @JohnLawler https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aboot mentions "aboot". I'm sorry if your feelings were hurt. It wasn't my intent.

Comment: @JohnLawler A Canadianism doesn't have to be a word. It can be any other language feature (see my first comment). If you type "canadianism" into Google, you get the definition I quoted.

Comment: @ColleenV I agree that it sounds more like "aboat" to me. Wikipedia mentions "aboot" though. I'll edit the question nevertheless.

Comment: It's _about_. Pronounced the way Canadians say it. Spelling it different is like spelling _with_ as _widh_ when it's voiced, which is about half the time.

Comment: Why are people closing the most on-topic of on-topic ELU questions as opnion-based?  This is a fact-based question. It is not asking for opinions. It may not be easy to -know- the answer but that doesn't it make it opinion based.

Comment: @JohnLawler: With all due respect, you might reconsider your closing-policy. I think questions like this are perfectly fine and on topic. It's not strongly advocating some opinion. I see no opinion in it.

Comment: @JohnLawler No one is claiming the word is "aboat" or "aboot". They are clearly using the deviant spelling to quickly communicate a difference a well-known pronunciation. I think you're too focused on an unimportant detail of the question.

Comment: I don't see why anybody cares what I think. I still think the way I did before. This is not a "canadianism", and the word is not spelled "aboot", or "aboat". That's for children. There's a subtle difference in the pronunciation of one diphthong -- too subtle for the media, and apparently also for all the professional linguists here at ELU. If you really want an answer to that question, you'll hafta commission a sociophonetic survey, which will cost a pretty penny. But then you'll know, for sure.

Comment: Could you re-phrase most of that? "Most Canadians" might live "close to the border…" but when you cross to the American side, how are you defining "in a rural area" or "Canadianisms"? Is this purely about "Canadianisms" or do "Americanisms" also count? How "suddenly" does anything change and how are you measuring "much less common"? Broadly, I'm suggesting that in its current form, the Question can't usefully be Answered.

Comment: The fact that the border is so porous and many people commute across it or travel over it for leisure or social reasons, and for most of its length the same language is spoken either side (excluding French-speaking regions), as well as the fact that radio and TV signals cross the border, will all tend to a lack of distinctions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, Canadian pronunciations of "about" (approximated as "aboat/aboot", IPA [ə.ˈbʌʊt] or [ə.ˈbɛʊt] in Southern Ontario) are not equally common on the American side of the border, adjacent to it.

Timothy Vance wrote about this question back in 1987 in his article ["Canadian Raising" in Some Dialects of the Northern United States](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.296.1640&rep=rep1&type=pdf), where he looked at both /aɪ/ raised to [ʌɪ] (as in [Canadian pronunciations](http://www.yorku.ca/twainweb/troberts/raising.html) of "knife") and /aʊ/ raised to [ʌʊ] (as in Canadian pronunciations of "about"). He found the latter to be **rarer** - though **not absent** - on the American side of the border.

As a Canadian linguist married to a woman from rural Western New York, I can confirm that this observation still holds true anecdotally in 2022. My wife's pronunciation and her family's pronunciation of "knife" are similar to mine, while their pronunciation of "about" is not. They're also very aware of this difference, even as non-linguists.

By the way, we have an authoritative resource on Canadianisms called [A Dictionary of Canadianisms on Historical Principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Dictionary_of_Canadianisms_on_Historical_Principles). It covers words, expressions, and meanings characteristic of Canadian English.

Answer (score 3):

When I was in Minnesota I heard people saying what I thought was 'aboot', and a fellow outsider (from New York) told me it was the Yooper (UP - Upper Pensinsula) accent. Years later, I heard an approximation of it in a film, *Fargo*, set in Minnesota.

Comment: What one hears a lot more in Fargo, is how they say Yeah.

Comment: @Lambie - and they say 'eh' at the end of sentences, too, which my Ontario cousin said is more common 'down there' than where she is.

Comment: Juno Temple does a very good rendition of the Minnesota accent in the current *Fargo* TV series.

Comment: @TimR - A treat I am awaiting eagerly. It's all lined up and ready to go, now that _True Detective_ has finished. Which, incidentally, I thought was brilliant, and I detected some 'northern' vowels.

Comment: Her lilt and intonation  are also very well done.

Answer (score 0):

Accent regions don't always conform with political borders. In the case of the so called "Canadian raising", there's some accents with it in the United States of America, most notably in the upper Midwest and parts of New England. Some upper Midwest and Canadian accents are so similar, that if you crossed a non-patrolled part of the border between the two countries, you would hardly be able to tell whether you were in the US or Canada just by hearing people talk, the main exception might be if they're discussing the weather, how far they live from where they are, etc (the Canadians will generally express those measurements in metric rather than imperial).

Outside the Midwest and New England, a few southern American accents also have the Canadian raising, at least in terms of the " ou" dipthong, the most notable of which is the "Tidewater" accent of Virginia.

Comment: The border is porous for tourists, but a Canadian can't just come to the US and decide to reside here, legally.

Comment: The top answer cites sources from 1987 saying that the Canadian raising is rarer on the US side of the border. If there are "raisers" on both sides of the border, you won't be able to tell, reliably, which side the speaker is from.